# Android Задать цвет фона для приложения программно, что бы при перезапуске цвет сохранился

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть обработчик для кнопки:

```
change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        bglayout.setBackgroundColor(333333);            
    }
});
```

Как сделать, что бы при перезапуске приложения это цвет сохранился?

Потенциально, не только цвет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для сохранения каких-либо (небольших) параметров между перезапусками приложения, Вы можете воспользоваться классом `SharedPreferences`.

Простой пример:

Добавляете в класс `Activity` поле:

```
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
```

Далее, в методе `onCreate()` загружаете и применяете сохраненный цвет (если он был сохранен):

```
mSettings = getSharedPreferences("my_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (mSettings.contains("my_background_color")) {
    int color = mSettings.getInt("my_background_color", 0);
    bglayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

А в методе `onStop()` сохраняете цвет:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
Drawable background = bglayout.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
    editor.putInt("my_background_color", ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor());
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Скажите, а такой метод подходит, что бы юзать его в настройках? то есть через интент передаем переменную, а потом ее просто задействуем. или это делают по-другому?

Comment: @JaredBay, Не очень понял вопрос, но если Вы спрашивали можно ли таким способом сохранять настройки приложения – да, можно.

Comment: вы правильно меня поняли :D спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 2):

В Android есть специальные методы в `Activity` для [сохранения/восстановления состояния](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru): [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=ru#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) и [`onRestoreInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?hl=ru#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

В `onSaveInstanceState` вы можете сохранить цвет кнопки:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // сохраняем цвет кнопки
    savedInstanceState.putInt("btn_bg", ((ColorDrawable) change.getBackground()).getColor());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

А в `onRestoreInstanceState` восстанавливаете:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // устанавливаем цвет, который сохранили перед закрытием пиложения
    change.setBackgroundColor(savedInstanceState.getInt("btn_bg"));   

}
```

Comment: "при перезапуске приложения" это работать не будет.